# Not running my Do While Loop

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am writing a simulation of a predator and prey, and have built a loop so it will always continue, yet for some reason my program does not run the loop at all. Any ideas? And yes I know my code is messy but I will sort that out later!

```
Public Class Form1
Dim intWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim intHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
Dim StartBase As Integer = 10
Dim Hunter(100, 1) As Integer
Dim Hunted(100, 1) As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
Dim blnFinished As Integer = False
Dim blnFirst As Boolean = True
Private Sub Form1_keydown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Form1_Paint(sender, e)
    Do While (blnFinished = False)
        Movement()
        Form1_Paint(sender, e)
        Form1_keydown(sender, e)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    Dim Y As Integer = 0
    If blnFirst = True Then
        RandomPosition(X, Y)
        For Me.intCount = 1 To StartBase
            X = CInt(Math.Floor(((intWidth) - 0 + 1) * Rnd())) + 0               'Assigns a random x coordinate
            Y = CInt(Math.Floor((intHeight - 250) - 0 + 1) * Rnd()) + 0        'Assigns a random y coordinate
            Hunted(intCount, 0) = X
            Hunted(intCount, 1) = Y                                         'Saves the x and y value to Hunted array
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, X, Y, 15, 15)      'Draws the hunted to the screen with earlier values
            X = CInt(Math.Floor(((intWidth) - 0 + 1) * Rnd())) + 0               'Assigns a random x coordinate
            Y = CInt(Math.Floor((intHeight - 250) - 0 + 1) * Rnd()) + 0        'Assigns a random y coordinate
            Hunter(intCount, 0) = X
            Hunter(intCount, 1) = Y                                         'Saves the x and y value to Hunted array
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Maroon, X, Y, 15, 15)   'Draws the hunted to the screen with earlier values
        Next
        blnFirst = False
    Else
        For Me.intCount = 1 To StartBase
            X = Hunted(intCount, 0)
            Y = Hunted(intCount, 1)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, X, Y, 15, 15)
            X = Hunter(intCount, 0)
            Y = Hunter(intCount, 1)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Maroon, X, Y, 15, 15)
        Next
    End If
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, intHeight - 235, intWidth, 200)
End Sub

Private Sub RandomPosition(X, Y)
    Randomize()
    X = CInt(Math.Floor((Width - 0 + 1) * Rnd())) + 0
    Y = CInt(Math.Floor((Height - 250) - 0 + 1) * Rnd()) + 0
End Sub

Private Sub Movement()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Change the type of blnFinished to boolean. You now have implicit type conversions.

Comment: Switch Option Strict On and fix the errors it will then throw up...

Comment: Calling event handlers directly (Form_paint, Form_KeyDown) is a sign of poor design.  You should not be calling those methods directly, and not inside Form_Load.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Form_Paint directly and passing in the values for `sender` and `e` from `Form_Load`.  However, Form_Paint expects `e` to be of type `System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs` whereas you are passing in an object of type `System.EventArgs` since that is what is being passed into Form_Load.  `System.EventArgs` does not have a property called `Graphics`.  So the line below (and others like it) is likely throwing an exception since the value of `e` that you passed in doesn't have a Graphics property:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGreen, X, Y, 15, 15)
```

And I think you're not seeing the exception because it occurs in Form_Load.  Run the program in debug mode and look in the output window.  The exception is probably shown there.  Or put a Try Catch around your code.

You might do better to use a timer and inside it's tick event, call `Form1.Refresh()`.  That will trigger the Paint event properly.